# "Between" Statement in Left Join Returns null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

OK, there's GOT to be an answer to this... likely a straightforward solution for one of the many experts here at Stack Overflow! :-)

Background:
I am trying to create a restaurant sales report by shift. I have 2 tables... one with **RECEIPT** details (*restaurant, date, time, receipt#, amount, server, etc.*) and another with **SHIFT** details (*restaurant, shift start time, shift end time & shift name*). There are *Shift Numbers* in both tables, but unfortunately the *Shift Numbers* in the Receipts table are not always accurate, so I am having to come up with a workaround based on which bucket of *ShiftStart* & *ShiftEnd* times the *ReceiptTime* falls into. This code for the join almost works:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN: Receipts.Time BETWEEN ShiftDetails.ShiftStartTime AND ShiftsDetails.ShiftEndTime
```

BUT... my challenge is that the Dinner *ShiftEndTime* is currently 02:00, which (of course) is **less** than the Dinner *ShiftStartTime* of 17:31, so any *ReceiptTimes* "between" these hours returns a null value. I would also like to keep the query dynamic by avoiding "hard coding" the *Start/End times*, instead using those in the Shift table, as they are likely to be revised in the future.

FWIW, my data source is SQL Server with Power BI as a front-end, so alternatively I could scrap the SQL code and perform magic with PowerQuery or DAX...

Many thanks in advance!
Danny

Comment: Apologies to JBrooks & Gordon Linoff for the (EXTREMELY!) late response... don't get on here much and happened to notice your helpful answers... THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of handling this logic:

```
Receipts r LEFT OUTER JOIN
ShiftDetails sd
ON (sd.ShiftStartTime <= sd.ShiftEndTime AND r.Time BETWEEN sd.ShiftStartTime AND sd.ShiftEndTime) OR
    (sd.ShiftStartTime > sd.ShiftEndTime AND r.Time BETWEEN sd.ShiftEndTime AND sd.ShiftStartTime)
```

You might decide that you really don't want `BETWEEN`.  Receipts that are exactly on the boundary between shifts will return both of them -- because `BETWEEN` includes the end points of the range.

Comment: It seems like the following shift starts one minute later, so the "between" approach should be fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a function that says if the shift end time is less than 4:00 AM than return the DateTime for the next day's date.

So it would be used in a join like:

```
WHERE ShiftEndDateTime <= dbo.EndShiftDateTime(@ShiftDate, @ShiftEndTime)
```

This bumps it to the next day if the hour is less than 5:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.EndShiftDateTime(@ShiftDate Date, @ShiftTime Time) 
  RETURNS DateTime
AS
BEGIN


IF(DATEPART(HOUR, @ShiftTime) < 5)
    SET @ShiftDate =  dateadd(day, 1, @ShiftDate)

RETURN cast(@ShiftDate as datetime)  + cast(@ShiftTime as datetime)         

END
```

I don't like hard coding an hour like this, but it is unlikely to ever change. You could make the logic to be more flexible (if endtime < starttime) but I've seen that that just leads to hard to find bugs.